# Unexpected `await` inside a loop no-await-in-loop

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an error inside the following loop:

> Unexpected `await` inside a loop no-await-in-loop

```
const deviceSet = {};
for (const target of body.inputs[0].payload.devices) {
    const doc = await firestore().doc(`devices/${target.id}`).get();
    const device = Device.createDevice(doc.id, doc.data());
    deviceSet[device.id] = device.reportState;
   }
```

Comment: You're seeing a linting error. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop

Comment: Is your function declared `async`?

Comment: fulfillment.onQuery(async (body, headers)

Answer (score 0):

You could try it the old fashioned way:

```
const deviceSet = {};
const target = body.inputs[0].payload.devices;
for (let i = 0; i < body.inputs[0].payload.devices; i++) {
    const doc = firestore().doc(`devices/${target[i].id}`).get();
    const device = Device.createDevice(doc.id, doc.data());
    deviceSet[device.id] = device.reportState;
   }
```

Comment: This may not work as `get()` returns a promise. So `doc` would be a promise not a value.

Comment: or `async function yourfunctionname(){
const doc = await ...
}; yourfunctionname();`

Comment: fulfillment.onSync(async (body, headers) => {
  try {
    const userId = validateCredentials(headers);
    // Return all devices registered to the requested user
    const result = await firestore.collection('devices').where('owner', '==', userId).get();
    const deviceList = result.docs.map(doc => {
      const device = Device.createDevice(doc.id, doc.data());
      return device.metadata;
    });

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop gives a solution to this linting error.

Answer (score 0):

Recurssion can solve your problem. This is not tested code, you can work on the idea

```
async function test(i = 0) {
  const deviceSet = {};
  const target = body.inputs[0].payload.devices;
  const doc = await firestore().doc(`devices/${target[i].id}`).get();
  const device = Device.createDevice(doc.id, doc.data());
  deviceSet[device.id] = device.reportState;
  if (i < body.inputs[0].payload.devices) {
    test(i + 1);
  }
}
test(0)
```